# PHP Fatal error: PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mmap failed: in Unknown on line 0

Tags: magento, apc

I am trying to get APC up and running for PHP (magento) but i have this weird problem which is bothering me. I have done my apc installation through the below command

pecl install apc
pecl/apc is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.13

and i have also added the configuration parameter in /etc/php.d/apc.ini as shown below

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.num_files_hint=10000
apc.user_entries_hint=10000
apc.max_file_size=100M
apc.stat=0
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.include_once_override=1
apc.shm_size=4
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
```

Before i thought that maybe my configuration is messing up but when i removed every line in the apc.ini file but still i am getting the below error when executing php --ini

> PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mmap failed: in Unknown on line 0
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Now i am really not sure what to do

My PHP version is 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue after experimenting with the different packages of APC. The tutorial which is out there can be quite confusing because every tutorial mentioning to install the APC with pecl might not work with PHP54.

So what you really need to do is get the correct package for the installation, in my case i issued the below command

```
yum install php54w-pecl-apc
```

Once i did that everything went smoothly. The apc.ini file was automatically got created with the basic configuration in location /etc/php.d

phpinfo had also listed the APC as configured.

**My php version**

php -v
PHP 5.4.11 (cli) (built: Jan 30 2013 18:05:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies